# Express GraphicsMagick

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, graphicsmagick

I'm currently building a MEAN app and the section I'm currently working on involves image uploads. I'm trying to use [GraphicsMagick for Node](http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html) but I'm not really having any success. Below is my POST request for image uploads (as is):

```
app.post('/api/users/upload_image', function (req, res) {
        var fstream;
        req.pipe(req.busboy);
        req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
            console.log('\n\nUploading file: '.underline.bold +filename .underline.bold);


            // var readStream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
            // gm(readStream, readStream.path)
            //  .resize('200','200')
            //  .stream(function (err, stdout, stderr) {
            //      var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('www/uploads/' + readStream.path);
            //      stdout.pipe(writeStream);
            //  });

            fstream = fs.createWriteStream('www/uploads/' + filename);
            file.pipe(fstream);

        });

        req.busboy.on('finish', function () {
            res.writeHead(303, { Connection: 'close', Location: '/' });
            res.end();
        });
    });
```

The commented out section is my attempt at using GM but that throws back the error: `Error: ENOENT, open '[filename].jpg'`

Where am I going wrong? This is my first try at using GM so I'm a newb to this library!

Comment: Is the file actually there? What happens if you use GraphicsMagick outside of an HTTP request, to isolate whether the problem is with your call to `gm` or with the connecting of a request to `gm`?

Comment: Yeah the file is there because the code as it is in the above block is saving the image thats passed through the form to the server. The problem seems to be with GM intercepting the file before it's saved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var readStream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
```

at this line file named filename is not actually there yet you write that file below the commented lines. What you have is read steam named `file` you get from busyboy. so get rid of this line and pass `file` to gm directly

```
gm(file,....
```

Code below does exactly what you want, note the gm's write function's parameters.

```
app.post('/api/users/upload_image', function (req, res) {
    req.pipe(req.busboy);
    req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
        console.log('\n\nUploading file: '.underline.bold +filename .underline.bold);

        console.log('Resizing file...');

        gm(file,'www/uploads/' + filename)
        .resize(200,200)
        .write('www/uploads/' + filename, function (err) {
            console.log("finished");
        });
    });

    req.busboy.on('finish', function () {
        res.writeHead(303, { Connection: 'close', Location: '/' });
        res.end();
    });
});
```

Note that gm's resize when used this way, simply fit's image in 200x200 box, does not exactly rescale/stretch it to 200x200.

If this still give you an error like EPIPE, your node process might not have sufficent permissions to write that file.

Comment: If i do this and then pass filename to the writestream instead of readstream.path then I get error: write EPIPE?

Comment: At which line you get EPIPE exactly? EPIPE means the other end closed the stream, before you complete reading/writing.

Comment: It doesn't actually give a line error specific to this function, you can see the full error I get in the answer above yours. I get the same error with both solutions.

Comment: in this case try to find which steam is giving this error. First take out `.steam(` and use gm's `write`. If you still get the error this means the error is coming from busboy's `file` readsteam.

Comment: I've kind of got it working but I'm not sure if it's right... This is what I have atm: http://pastie.org/pastes/9214877/text?key=7zwffbkme4ov4p3nqhg - it's saving the file from within gm which is a step in the right direction I guess but the problem that I'm now having is that gm's .resize isn't working and the file is saved to the server with it's original size instead of 200x200. I've tried 200,200 & '200','200'

Comment: write takes a filename as first parameter `.write('/path/to/file.png', function (err) {
  if (!err) console.log('done');
});`

Comment: Yeah that's what I tried from the other answer and that blocks returns EPIPE. I don't see how the connection is being closed?

Comment: Can you upload a small project isolated to this problem?

Comment: that wouldn't really work would it because it's happening in the CLI. Here's the whole upload_image POST req though: http://pastie.org/pastes/9218474/text?key=qswnycucptrtb3pbsmvojq

Comment: What i meant was a nodejs project zipped up and uploaded somewhere so i can run the the project on my local node test env and see what is this all about

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54443/discussion-between-quad-and-leaksterrr).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to read the file before it's written. If you don't need to save the original image, you could just stream the file directly to gm instead:

```
req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
    console.log('\n\nUploading file: '.underline.bold +filename .underline.bold);

    console.log('Resizing file...');
    gm(file, filename)
     .resize('200','200')
     .write('www/uploads/' + filename, function(err) {
       if (err) throw err; // handle better
       console.log('Success!'.bold);
     });
});
```

You should probably also check that the given mime type of the file matches what you expect (e.g. `image/jpeg`, `image/png`, etc). You could also take that a step farther by using something like [mmmagic](https://github.com/mscdex/mmmagic) to check the file type. However with mmmagic, you would have to forgo the direct streaming to gm option and save the file to disk first.

Comment: I've done exactly as you've said here and now I'm getting a totally different message that I don't understand which is (tried to format it): `events.js:72 ... throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event ... Error: write EPIPE at ... errnoException (net.js:904:11) ... at Object.afterWrite (net.js:720:19)`